# Trying to understand iptables log messages

Tags: iptables

I have set up iptables to log outgoing traffic from all but a limited set of users, and I'm trying to understand the log messages that this produces. Looking at /var/log/syslog, I see requests from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.53 (DNS lookups?) and quite a few to 224.0.0.22 that look like this:

```
IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=10.100.102.200 DST=224.0.0.22 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 MARK=0x94
```

which is a multicast address... any ideas what would be causing this?

Finally, I have several that look like this, which seem to be outgoing ICMP requests addressed to various places around the world:

```
IN= OUT=wlp2s0 SRC=10.100.102.200 DST=151.80.9.69 LEN=138 TOS=0x08 PREC=0xC0 TTL=64 ID=26846 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=151.80.9.69 DST=10.100.102.200 LEN=110 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=51 ID=48812 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=27209 DPT=8083 LEN=90 ]
```

But, what really puzzles me is the bit in the brackets (`SRC=151.80.9.69 PROTO=UDP SPT=27209 DPT=8083`). Does mean the ICMP packet is a response to a UDP request to port 8083? Should I be worried that this is a possible intrusion (or attempted intrusion)? And if so, is there any reason why I shouldn't block all incoming UDP traffic? (I only have webservers listening on ports 80 and 443, and no other ports are open -- I've checked and double-checked this.)

Grateful for any help understanding what I'm seeing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate answers for separate bits of questions

- `224.0.0.22` is the [multicast address for IGMP](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/2039/why-am-i-seeing-lots-of-traffic-to-2240022/), which stays on your local network
- `127.0.0.53` is the `systemd` DNS resolver
- Your `PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3` outgoing packets are "[Port unreachable](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/ICMP-error-message-format-ICMP-error-messages-of-Type-3-represent-a-destination_fig1_332993177)" responses to attempts from `151.80.9.69` to send a UDP message to `10.100.102.200` on port `8083`

  In order for traffic to reach `10.100.102.200` on `udp/8083` the server must be reachable through NAT and port forwarding. Either because you used to run a service on `udp/8083` and the NAT has not yet timed out despite you no longer running that service (just a matter of seconds or minutes), or because you have a static port forwarding through your NAT layer.

Comment: Many thanks. The UDP is puzzling; netstat shows that there is nothing listening on 8083, and an external port scan shows only 80 and 443 open to the outside (which has always been the case), so I've no idea why I'm seeing these at all. I'm getting the same thing from other IP addresses around the world, and directed to various different ports. The router is sending all incoming traffic to this machine.

Comment: By the way, is there somewhere where this sort of stuff is documented? I haven't managed to find anything other than very general stuff about how to interpret the log messages

Comment: I'm not aware of anywhere else that will answer all these questions in one go. I've linked to my sources (evidence, if you will) although I did know what I was looking for. I've not seen the `[   ]` construct before, but knowing that `icmp/3,3` is "Port unreachable" allowed me to interpret the bracketed field

Comment: OK, thanks for the help.